# Starting with assumption (inequality induction)

Tags: inequality, induction

My teacher has always told me that when doing inequality induction proofs,  for the $k+1$ step, I should always start with the expression for $k+1$ and then somehow manipulate it so that I can plug in the assumption. Then prove the statement. However, I recently came across this video of a teacher starting directly with the assumption: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VLSjyUa2aA

Is this valid and if so, why isn't it taught more widely (doesn't mention it in my textbook either)? I personally find this technique much easier to follow.

Comment: Why did you delete your earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2568830/42969 – for which you already got an answer – and posted the same question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine.

- Basically the induction hypothesis is a tool that is given to you.
- The $(k+1)$-th case is what you want to show. Your goal.

As long as you can show the $(k+1)$-th case, it is up to you how do you want to use your tool. You can either use it at the beginning as the video shown, or you can use it as an intermediate tool.

In fact, for this particular case, it is almost identical.

\begin{align}
\text{LHS of what you want to show} &= 3^{k+1} \\
&= 3 (3^k) \\
& \geq 3(1+2k) \\
&=  3+6k\\
&= 2k + 3+ 4k\\
&\geq 2k+3\\
&=\text{RHS  of what you want to show}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's perfectly valid.

Now, I am not sure that I agree with your claim that it is not taught more widely ... and I certainly object to your argument/evidence that it is not taught more widely: just because your teacher and your textbook never follow this method does not mean that it is not widely taught: You make a hasty generalization from two (probably not independent) cases!